# do not send local mails to relay

Tags: linux, email

We have an issue on linux servers sending local mails to the smart relay.
every time a cron job runs, and an  email is sent to root. it is send to the relay instead of being delivered locally in /var/spool/mail/root.

this is the output of a test email sent to root:

```
echo test | mailx -v root
root... Connecting to smtpp.example.com. via relay...
220 EXCHP12.example.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 12 Oct 2023 15:50:51 +0200
>>> EHLO vm.example.com
250-EXCHP12.example.com Hello [x.x.x.x]
250-SIZE 37748736
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
>>> MAIL From:<root@vm.example.com> SIZE=185
250 2.1.0 Sender OK
>>> RCPT To:<root@vm.example.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 Recipient OK
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
>>> .
250 2.6.0 <202310121350.39CDolG52072267@vm.example.com> [InternalId=167383465460805, Hostname=EXCHP22.example.com] 1730 bytes in 0.134, 12.593 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery
root... Sent (<202310121350.39CDolG52072267@vm.example.com> [InternalId=167383465460805, Hostname=EXCHP22.example.com] 1730 bytes in 0.134, 12.593 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
Closing connection to smtpp.example.com.
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
```

the default mta of the server is sendmail.sendmail according to the `alternatives --list` output, however sendmail service is not running on the server.

when i use sendmail to test the email. it is correctly put in /var/spool/mail/root

```
echo 'test' | sendmail -Am -d60.5 -v root
map_lookup(dequote, root, %0=root) => NOT FOUND (0)
map_lookup(dequote, root, %0=root) => NOT FOUND (0)
root... Connecting to local...
root... Sent
```

how come mailx is sending root mails to relay?

how to stop root local emails being forwarded the the smart relay.